# Could you recommend me a server-side javascript parser?

Tags: php, javascript, serverside-javascript

I have to extract defined variable and function names from a js code passed as a text. Example:

```
$js_code = " var MyVar1 = 'val1'; \n var MyVar2 = 'val2' ; \n function MyFunc() { some code }";
```

Extracted:

```
$js_vars = array("MyVar1", "MyVar2");
$js_func = array("MyFunc");
```

Comment: no recommendation here, but a quick google search led me to http://timwhitlock.info/jparser/

Comment: Is it possible for you to send these variables as a JSON object? That would make things far more easy: in that case you could just use `json_decode` on the server.

Comment: I think it isn't possible. I send a textarea value to the server. I don't know a way to transform a string like the example one into JSON encoding/decoding data.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel that's a good idea, i had thought it as well, but assumed there was a reason why not, heh. You're right though, @Stefan K, JSON can't handle a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Aptana Jaxer?
It's an HTTP/Apache javascript parser.

There's also tools like jParser: http://timwhitlock.info/jparser/
Which is a php library which parses javascript.
That might be more like what you need, but only if you're using PHP server-side.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I knew jParser library. Yes, it's more like what I need but I would like to test and another parser. Thanks for the answer.